# Select item from fileListBox

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I have create a fileListBox and explore a folder with .jpg file, at click item the picturebox1 show the image selected..but is possible create a button to select the next item and previous?

Comment: What are you using Winforms, WPF or something else? Do you mean [this `FileListBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.compatibility.vb6.filelistbox.aspx)?

Comment: yes it is..i use Windows Form

Answer (score 0):

next:

```
fileListBox.SelectedIndex = fileListBox.SelectedIndex + 1;
```

previous:

```
fileListBox.SelectedIndex = fileListBox.SelectedIndex-1;
```

You may want to check if you are at the end or beginning before doing this, or catch exceptions

Answer (score 0):

Select Next:

```
If fileListBox.SelectedIndex < fileListBox.Items.Count-1 Then
   fileListBox.SelectedIndex = fileListBox.SelectedIndex+1
End If
```

Select Previous:

```
If fileListBox.SelectedIndex > 0 Then
   fileListBox.SelectedIndex = fileListBox.SelectedIndex-1
End If
```

You might also want to actually enable/disable the buttons based on if it's even possible to select the previous or next:

```
btnSelectNext.Enabled = fileListBox.SelectedIndex < fileListBox.Items.Count-1
btnSelectPrevious.Enabled = fileListBox.SelectedIndex > 0
```